# XSL issue : making selective xml but with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following input xml:

```
<class xmlns:xfa="soommmeee-tteexxxxtttttt">
    <students>
        ----------
        -----------
        ----------
    </students>
    <students>
        <id>B</id>
        <name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
        <description>mjZSVxcj</description>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <friend>hercules</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <friend>aladin</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <friend>aladin</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>4</id>
            <refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>75</id>
                <name>PCM</name>
                <friend>hercules</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>j4423</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>sdbnfn</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>masdjkljk</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>msjkldbhfjkn</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <students>
    ------------
    --------------
    </students>
    <faculty>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Output</Type>
            <Key>Font</Key>
            <Value>10pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Out</Type>
            <Key>Text</Key>
            <Value>127,127,127</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>put</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>18pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>utp</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>127</Value>
        </configuration>
    </faculty>
    <Info />
    <Dean>
        <name>zcdfjkaqbkd</name>
    </Dean>
</class>
```

i want an xsl who takes out the whole section of 'students' including the subsection of 'student' but only those student should be consisted in the new xml which has their friend as 'hercules'. its not cumplsary that 'hercules' will be consisted in any one of the student it can be in more than one too and maybe under different different 'students' section too

i am not getting any idea regarding this....i have gone through many examples but unable to do it

say my desired output be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class xmlns:xfa="soommmeee-tteexxxxtttttt">
    <students>
        <id>B</id>
        <name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
        <description>mjZSVxcj</description>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <friend>hercules</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>4</id>
            <refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>75</id>
                <name>PCM</name>
                <friend>hercules</friend>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>j4423</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>sdbnfn</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>masdjkljk</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>msjkldbhfjkn</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <faculty>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Output</Type>
            <Key>Font</Key>
            <Value>10pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Out</Type>
            <Key>Text</Key>
            <Value>127,127,127</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>put</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>18pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>utp</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>127</Value>
        </configuration>
    </faculty>
    <Info />
    <Dean>
        <name>zcdfjkaqbkd</name>
    </Dean>
</class>
```

i think i am clear with the idea and if there is anything i can do to explain more the please comment......thanks from now only

Below is the xsl i am using right now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="Selected non-Selected">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vResultSelected">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="Selected" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 2">
            <xsl:result-document
                href="SectionOutput\{'Selected'[position()=current()]}.xml">
                <xsl:copy-of select="($vResultSelected)[position() = current()]" />
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="Selected"
        match="students/*[not(*/friend = 'hercules')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems to be a very basic XSLT filtering issue. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcusRickert have included the xslt i am using....please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach has several flaws built into it:

- First of all, your approach is way to complicated. You are using `output-document` although you are interested in a single XML outfile. `output-document` usually comes in handy if you have to split you result across *several* XML output files. If you have the need to to this you should update your expected result accordingly.
- You are using several different `mode`s for your templates but the modes are not called in corresponding `apply-templates`, so, as an effect they will never be called.
- You are using the select syntax `1 to 2` which is not valid since the select should contain an xquery expression. Also, how do you know that it will be 1 through 2? This would only be valid for this concrete XML input file, wouldn't it?

Please, find an suggestion for your problem below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="students[not(.//friend = 'hercules')]"/>

  <xsl:template match="student[not(.//friend = 'hercules')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It basically uses three elements:

- A template with match `*|@*` which makes sure we copy everything to the output file that is not explicitly handled by a more specific template.
- A template which matches the `students` tag who do not have at least one `student` with a friend called "hercules". For these we don't do anything resulting in the whole subtree of the `students` to be discarded.
- A template which matches the `student`s who do not have a friend called "hercules". For these we don't do anything resulting in the whole subtree of of the `student` to be discarded.

Comment: Hi Marcus, i tried the above code but it is copying the 'students' node excluding the 'student' node in the area where it does not have a 'friend' as 'hercules'....please take a look at the desired output....you may get an idea...thanks

Comment: if there is multiple friends as 'hercules' then it is copying the whole 'students' node irrespective of any filter

Comment: As far as I can see the output of my script exactly matches your expected output. If you think that the filtering should be different please update your input XML and expected XML to reflect this.

Comment: what i am asking is i want an xsl which transforms my xml in such a way that it takes out all the 'student' nodes which has 'hercules' as a 'friend'...but if any of the 'student' in the 'students' tag has a 'friend' as 'hercules' then it should not be presented there....and the filtered data should.....you got it now?

Comment: Not, really. As I said: please, update your input XML and your expected XML to include a constellation that is not handled correctly in my suggested XSLT and let's continue from there then.